# How to get all values from an array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have an varible that retrive and stores values in an array format. That is

```
$fold_location = Input::get('location');
```

If we Print this means it look like below:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

What i want is to get all values from this variable.

i am trying the following.

```
    foreach($fold_location as $value) {
                    $fold_location = $value;
                    print_r($fold_location);
    }
```

But it return the output as 1.
 I want to get all the values. How to do that in php -mysql

Comment: It is already there in the array. How do you want get this?

Comment: First this has nothing to do with MySQL, and second `$fold_location` already contains all the values. So I have no idea what you're trying to achieve with your `foreach()` which is overwriting the array with a single value.

Comment: i want to get only the values only. for example 1 and 2 . but in the above code returns only 1

Comment: Because you are overwriting `$fold_location` inside the loop.

Comment: `$fold_location[] = $value;` to print array.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe OP want's to access the values outside the loop.

Comment: Try by replacing your foreach loop with the code in answer

Answer (score 1):

You do override your Array in the loop. Try:

```
foreach($array as $item) print_r($item);
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Array values using the PHP's array_values() function. You need not do a foreach()

```
<?php
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
?>
```

Output of the above code will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: The difference is, we get all the values in an array back. What the OP is trying to do is he's overriding the varaiable, by running in a foreach

Comment: It is already `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )`. What would `array_values` return if applied?

Comment: I think you did not understand his question. And what he's trying to ask, try to understand the question **"But it return the output as 1"**.

Comment: That is because OP is overwriting the variable inside the loop.

Comment: Before anyone downvotes this answer, Don't simply use the downvote, bcz its provided over there. Try to read the question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your foreach loop with below code.

```
foreach($fold_location as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```